# Did Leibniz sketch a design for a machine capable of solving a system of linear equations?

Tags: mathematicians, biographical-details, linear-algebra, computers, leibniz

My question is based on the information on pages 108-109 of the book [The Tangled Origins of the Leibnizian Calculus](https://doi.org/10.1142/8413). I know that Leibniz

- invented the stepped drum and used it to build the stepped reckoner — the first mechanical calculator capable of doing all four arithmetical operations.
- sketched a design for a different machine‚ the pinwheel calculator.
- designed a cipher machine.
- developed binary arithmetic (based on $0$ and $1$) and established its importance for computers, and even described in detail some of the fundamental principles of the modern computer (in his treatise *De progressione Dyadica*).

With such achievements in hand, it's not an exageration to believe the statement in this book.

Can someone give a reference for Leibniz's supposed machine? Can someone give a reference for a drawing of Leibniz machine (how does it look like?)?

Comment: I mean my conjecture about "a machine capable of solving a system of linear equations". All the other machines i mentioned were at least at the design stage (while the stepped reckoner was also built by him).

Comment: I come more and more to be convinced that a design of such complicated machine by leibniz is possible. Many websites state that leibniz designed far more complex machines than his stepped reckoner.

Comment: See also FLORIN-STEFAN MORAR, [Reinventing machines: the transmission history of the Leibniz calculator](http://journals.cambridge.org/action/displayAbstract?fromPage=online&aid=9544949&fulltextType=RA&fileId=S0007087414000429) (2015).

Comment: Mauro ALLEGRANZA, is this article concerned with Leibniz's stepped reckoner or with his machine capable of solving equations (Constructeur Universel d'Equations) ? i ask because i dont need references for articles about the stepped reckoner (i know how the stepped reckoner worked).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found an indirect reference into:

- [Joseph Ehrenfried Hofmann](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joseph_Ehrenfried_Hofmann), [Leibniz in Paris 1672-1676](http://www.cambridge.org/us/academic/subjects/history/history-science-and-technology/leibniz-paris-1672-1676-his-growth-mathematical-maturity) (1974, German ed.1949), page 30 and footnote 27:

> still in 1674 he [Leibniz] has plans for constructing an "analytical" counterpart to his calculating machine, an instrument for determining the solutions of equations, and he actually succeeds in doing so [*footnote 27*]
>
> *Footnote 27* for details see Hofmann (1970) [["Uber fruhe mathematische Studien von G.W.Leibniz", *Studia Leibnitiana*, 2, 81-114](http://www.jstor.org/stable/40693589?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents)] : 101-4. The instrument is mentioned in letters to Oldenburg: June, July, Dec.1675; also in L-Huygens, mid-Sept.1675. From Huygens' rather cautious reply, 30 Sept.1675 we may conclude that he has seen a sketch of the "Compas d'equation", as had Tschirnhaus according to Leibniz's letter, 8 Jan.1694. [...] A similar instrument is described in the [Encyclopédie, Suppl.II (1776): 834-5](https://books.google.it/books?id=zGREAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA834) (with an illustration in the [Planche suppl.(1777)](http://www.biodiversitylibrary.org/item/156186#page/361/mode/1up)) under "Algèbre". This instrument works for quadratic equations only, but it is justly claimed as a prototype capable of adaptation to higher equations. The inventor is not named: he might indeed have been inspired by the hint in G.W.Leibniz, [Der Briefwechsel mit Mathematikern I (Berlin 1899): 146](https://archive.org/stream/derbriefwechselv00leibuoft#page/146/mode/2up) since the passage was available in print, in John Wallis, [Opera mathematica III (Oxford 1699): 620-2](https://books.google.it/books?id=TSEtJ31s0w4C&pg=PA620) where the letter in question is reproduced, and in [Commercium Epistolicum (1712): 45](https://books.google.it/books?id=YDgPAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA45) where an excerpt is given [...].

Comment: So certainly Leibniz did design such a machine. That's already an advance (before your answer i wasn't sure if the statement in the book is correct). I'm unable to read the references you gave since i dont know german or french, so i'll ask only if you have a reference in english or at least a drawing of the machine.

Comment: @user2554 - I've added the link to the *Planche* in the *Suppl* (1777) to the *Encyclopédie*, illustrating the [Constructeur Universel d'Equations](http://www.biodiversitylibrary.org/item/156186#page/361/mode/1up).

Comment: Thanks you very much. The machine  isn't similar to what i imagined (i imagined an enourmous machine with huge number of gears), so i guess it's probably more ingenius. It's regretable that so little of leibniz's technical writings were translated to english - they might have an extraordinary positive impact on people who want to trace back technological ideas and understand, for example, the history of mechanical computers.